# Question about components of dynamic web project in this eclipse: Web Content and java resources are not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, web, path

I installed Eclipse and created a web project, and the components are coming out differently than anyone else.

There is a folder called src/main/java instead of a folder called java resources, and you can see src and its subfolders instead of Webcontent. Please help me. I can also attach a picture.

Answer (score 1):

The *default* paths [were changed](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.21/NewAndNoteworthy/#Modernized%20default%20paths) in 3.21, the 2021-03 release. You can still enter the old ones if you go through the other wizard pages when creating projects. And **Java Resources** was never an actual folder, just an organizational tree node specific to the **Project Explorer** view. Your Java Build Path entries will now be directly under the project, just like in the **Package Explorer**.

```
WebContent -> src/main/webapp
src -> src/main/java
```